# Are there any mountaineering/hiking activities in or near Albufeira, Portugal?

Tags: hiking, mountaineering, portugal

I'm heading over to Albufeira and I was just wondering if there are any **hiking** or **mountaineering** activities, or **outdoor landmarks** worth seeing in the area (or close by).

I don't want to be stuck on the beach with my friends the whole holiday, and from what I can see on [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attractions-g189112-Activities-Albufeira_Faro_District_Algarve.html) it's just beaches/typical tourist stuff.

Anyone know of any, through resources/personal experiences local to there?

**Note**:

- I would define local as probably within 25 miles of Albufeira.
- I haven't been to Portugal previously, so I'm unaware of any of the surrounding areas. (I'll be going off Google Maps or a real map of some kind only)

Comment: X-post: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/92999/45949

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it fits better to travel.SX and already has an answer [there](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92999/are-there-any-mountaineering-hiking-activities-in-or-near-albufeira-portugal).

Comment: @Wills, I know I asked the question and was recommended to come here.

Comment: @Wills, The mountaineering tag specifies in its first line _"This tag should be used with questions that discuss about possible places for mountaineering in a specific region"_, are you sure you're right it being off-topic? or would that tag wiki need to be changed?

Comment: Voting to leave open.  Being in scope at another site does not make it out of scope at this site.

Comment: Bradley, would it be wrong to ask you to take out the reference to the day of the week you're leaving? I started Googling places (I don't have any first hand knowledge), but then thought you might not need them because you'd be gone by tomorrow! I know the question is for all future visitors, not just you, but I wonder if leaving out the day of the week might be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Sue no problem at all, such a statement makes sense.

Comment: Great, thanks. Also, when you get back, it would be great to self-answer this with things you found. Even if we're able to look up some good things for you, first hand experience will be very valuable!

Comment: @Sue anything to contribute to a beta on SE. I'll be sure to delve into the details!